# Sklearn Multiclass Dataset Loading

Tags: python, dataset, scikit-learn

For a multiclass problem I use Scikit-Learn. I find very little examples on how to load a custom dataset with multiple classes. The `sklearn.datasets.load_files` method does not seem to be suitable as files need to be stored multiple times. I now have the following structure:

X => Python list with lists of features (in text).

y => Python list with lists of classes (in text).

How do I transform this to a structure Scikit-Learn can use in a classifier?

Comment: How does your dataset (or a subset of it look like) and what would be your desired result after the transformation?

Comment: (1) The dataset loaded into sklearn should be in numeric form, not strings or  anything other than numbers (2) the column, assigned to output, having separate floats like `0.0, 1.0,2.0, 3.0` would qualify for a multiclass classifier. Does this help?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
    import numpy as np
    from sklearn.preprocessing import MultiLabelBinarizer

    X = np.loadtxt('samples.csv', delimiter=",")
    y_aux = np.loadtxt('targets.csv', delimiter=",")
    y = MultiLabelBinarizer().fit_transform(y_aux)
```

**Code explanation**: Let's say you have all your features stored in a file called `samples.csv` and the multiclass labels in another file called `targets.csv` (they could be of course stored in the same file and you'd just need to split columns). For clarity in this example my files contain:

- `samples.csv`
  4.0,3.2,5.5
  6.8,5.6,3.3
- `targets.csv`
  1,4 <-- sample one belongs to classes 1 and 4
   
  2,3 <-- sample two belongs to classes 2,3

`MultiLabelBinarizer` encodes the output targets in such a way that `y` variable is **ready to be fed into Multiclass classifiers**. The output of the code is:

```
y = array([[1, 0, 0, 1],
   [0, 1, 1, 0]])
```

meaning sample one belongs to classes 1 and 4 and sample two belongs to 2 and 3.